# CASE Function in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle10g, case

I have a few questions about CASE function used in ORACLE.

When you use the CASE function, the data types used in all expressions must be the same.

The syntax of the CASE is:

```
CASE expr WHEN comparison_expr1 THEN return_expr1
          WHEN comparison_expr2 THEN return_expr2
          WHEN comparison_exprn THEN return_exprn
ELSE expr 
END
```

The data types for expr, comparison_expr, and return_expr must be the same.

There are two examples that baffle me

```
1. SELECT last_name, salary, job_id,
(CASE JOB_ID WHEN 'IT_PROG' THEN 1.10 * SALARY
            WHEN 'ST_CLERK' THEN 1.15 * SALARY
            WHEN 'SA_REP' THEN 1.20 * SALARY
            ELSE  SALARY END) "REVISED SALARY"
            FROM EMPLOYEES;




2.  SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY,
(CASE  WHEN SALARY<5000 THEN 'LOW'
       WHEN SALARY<10000 THEN 'MEDIUM'
       WHEN SALARY<20000 THEN 'GOOD'
       ELSE 'EXCELLENT' END) "QUALIFIED SALARY"
       FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

These two queries can be executed with no problem.

In the first example, you can see the value of job_id is decoded. The questions are:
1. Why are the data types for expr(job_id=varchar2) and return expr(1.10 * SALARY=numeric) different?
2. In the second example, if I use "salary" the way job_id is used in #1, the query results in an error. Why? The edited query is like:

```
        SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY,
(CASE **SALARY** WHEN SALARY<5000 THEN 'LOW'
             WHEN SALARY<10000 THEN 'MEDIUM'
             WHEN SALARY<20000 THEN 'GOOD'
             ELSE 'EXCELLENT' END) "QUALIFIED SALARY"
             FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  You seem to understand the right way to use `case`.  That is how SQL is designed.

Comment: In the last example, I put "salary" the way "job_id" is written in the first example. It gives an error when I execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple CASE expression, the expr and all comparison_expr values must either have the same datatype (CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2, NUMBER, BINARY_FLOAT, or BINARY_DOUBLE) or must all have a numeric datatype.

For both simple and searched CASE expressions, all of the return_exprs must either have the same datatype (CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2, NUMBER, BINARY_FLOAT, or BINARY_DOUBLE) or must all have a numeric datatype.

So the expr and the comparison_expr are related but not the return_expr.

For your second question, `salary` is a numeric field while `salary<1000` is an expression that returns boolean so different datatype, hence rule 1 is broken. That's why you get an error.

Refer to [case expressions explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will definitely go through it.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example `JOB_ID` is related to *comparison expressions* (i.e. `'IT_PROG'`, `'ST_CLERK'`, and `'SA_REP'`) while `SALARY` is related to the *result expressions*:

```
--------          Comparison ---- Result
(CASE JOB_ID WHEN 'IT_PROG'  THEN 1.10 * SALARY
             WHEN 'ST_CLERK' THEN 1.15 * SALARY
             WHEN 'SA_REP'   THEN 1.20 * SALARY
                             ELSE  SALARY END) "REVISED SALARY"
```

The types of comparison expressions are the same; the types of result expressions are the same, too. However, comparison expressions and result expressions are allowed to have a different type.

The second code snippet is an example of a different syntax - the so called [*searched case expression*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm). It is different from the first snippet, which is called *simple case expression*. It is an entirely different situation, because there is no search expression at all: the second syntax requires individual conditions, such as `SALARY<5000`, to be provided instead. See information at the link for the differences.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What about the third example? It looks like it's a searched CASE expression. If it were to write in simple CASE, how would it be?

Comment: @DrasticdreamerDrasticity The third example uses a broken syntax: it tries to mix up the simple syntax with a searched syntax, but the search expressions (boolean conditions) have a type incompatible with the search variable `SALARY`, which is numeric.